Не получается клонировать git репозиторий (публичный) в докер-образ
Контекст:
Собираю Докер-образ который будет стягивать с гита свежий код, разворачивать и собирать билд (Laravel + React) по отдельным папкам
Структура:

backend - Докерфайл и Laravel
frontend - Докерфайл и React
database - Конфиг + MySQL
nginx - конфиг + веб-сервер
docker-compose.yml - сборка

Проблема:
Бэкенд Докерфайл собирает образ РНР 8.1 и после этого должен стянуть проект на Ларке с гита:
Команда RUN git clone <repo> - ничего не делает, хотя должна стянуть проект.
Пробовал ставить простой публичный репозиторий, но тоже ничего не происходит. В папке нет проекта. Команда как будто просто игнорируется. При этом команды который находятся ДО и ПОСЛЕ git clone выполняются как надо (WORKDIR, EXPOSE, CMD, etc.)
Еще пробовал скачать архив через команду ADD <archive_download_url> и через wget <archive_download_url> но ничего не вышло
Добавлял команду git clone в первую инструкцию RUN где ставятся зависимости (поставил в конце). Тоже не помогло
Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libonig-dev \
    zip \
    libzip-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl && \
    pecl install xdebug-3.2.1 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    # Clear cache
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www && useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Change current user to www
USER www

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN git clone <public_repo_url>

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]


Ну для того чтобы выполнить RUN git нужно сначала установить git через пакет приложений типа apt, apt-get или другого - пример RUN apt-get install -y git

@DanielProtopopov пакет git установлен. Я не стал  скидывать весь Докерфайл, но перед выполнением команды RUN git clone выполняется установка пакетов, в числе которых есть и сам git

Прикрепляйте его тут, иначе будем гадать на кофейной гуще

@DanielProtopopov прикрепил

Запускается это все через docker-compose, в котором папка с проектом монтируется в контейнер?

@abu да. в Контейнер монтируется папка backend. Туда и нужно стянуть проект из гита

Скорее всего проблема: на билде в контейнер стягивается и кладется проект, а на композе туда же монтруется пустая папка и перетирает проект. Проверить можно: либо не монтировать папку и проверить, что проект в контейнере есть, либо предварительно склонить проект в папку, которая монтируется в контейнер.

@abu я проверил через docker compose up -d --build и там сначала была ошибка прав доступа и я убрал команду создания Юзера www и попробовал снова. Проект стянулся но папка была пуста. Я склонировал в другую папку '/var/tmp/' и там проект появился. Скорее всего ваша догадка верная, но теперь другая проблема:
Я не могу ни скопировать проект в мою рабочую папку 'var/www/' ни переместить туда. Причем как в Докерфайле так и в консоли после билда. Мне отдельный вопрос создать для этого или здесь продолжать?

@Jasik не совсем, понял проблему. Проект (код на Ларавеле) должен быть на хостовой машине в отдельной папке, доступной для докеркомпоза. На композе ее нужно смонтировать в рабочий каталог в контейнер при помощи композной опции volumes

@abu Я хотел сделать так, чтобы при сборке проекта с гита стягивалась актуальная версия проекта на Ларавел. Тоже самое планировал сделать и с фронтенд частью

@Jasik Обычно бидл выполняется в контексте каталога с докерфайлом, в котором располагается в том числе и код. Который, в ходе билда, полностью или частично, копируется в имидж. Это удобно, потому что билдить можно сразу несколько имиджей. Например, Ваш проект копируется в контейнер fpm, а его public часть - в nginx. Под это же заточены Gitlab CI, Github Actions и.т.д
Но в любом случае, если нужно монтировать проект с хоста (напр, для разработки), проект ДОЛЖЕН быть внутри контекста сборки ДО монтирования.

@Jasik Стоит склонить папку с проектом себе на машину и монтировать ее в контейнер при запуске
